# How to use The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined in ado.net EF

Tags: linq-to-entities

I have two table tblRole and tblUser. the tblUser have a feild of "RoleID" relate to tblRole.

follwing some main code:

```
            tblUserDao userDao = new tblUserDao();
            tblRoleDao roleDao = new tblRoleDao();
            var usr = userDao.GetUserByID(8);
            if (usr != null)
            {
                usr.RealName = "XXXX";
                var role = roleDao.GetRoleByID(4);
                usr.tblRole = role;
                isSuc = userDao.Updata(usr);
            }

public tblUser GetUserByID(int userID)
    {
        using (TOMSDBEntities tomsEntities = new TOMSDBEntities())
        {
            var tUser = tomsEntities.tblUser.Include("tblRole").Where(u => u.UserID == userID).FirstOrDefault();
            return tUser;
        }
    }

public bool Updata(tblUser model)
    {
        using (TOMSDBEntities tomsEntities = new TOMSDBEntities())
        {
            tomsEntities.GetObjectByKey(model.EntityKey);
            tomsEntities.ApplyPropertyChanges(model.EntityKey.EntitySetName, model);

            return (tomsEntities.SaveChanges() > 0);
        }
    }
```

now, report a error, it is **The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because they are attached to different ObjectContext objects.**

Answer (score 0):

Error message is prety self-explanatory, objects you return from your GetUserByID and GetRoleById are attached to different DataContexts..
My Guess is you are using different repositories for roles and users..

Either consider merging them into one repository with same context or create context elsewhere and pass  it as a parameter to repositories.

Comment: Hi Alexander Taran, thank you very mach. because I use three layout framework in my system. now, I want to know other use linq to entities in n-tier application. I don't know your meaning. would u detailedly tell me?